# FFMPEG video doesn't work on mobile and social media

Tags: ffmpeg, video, media

So we are creating short videos from image sequences. The videos work on computer but on mobile they don't play, on instagram we can't upload, on WhatsApp it doesn't show thumbnails.

Here is our code:

```
ffmpeg -y -f image2 -r 1/".$request->speed." -i ".public_path()."/media/v_images/".$request->folder."/photo%d.png -vcodec libx264 -crf 30 -vf fps=30 -pix_fmt yuv420p ".public_path()."/media/videos/".$video->name.".mp4
```

Videos specs:

- Min 40 seconds length
- 30 frame per seconds
- Video bitrate 113kbps
- Min video size 200 KB

Comment: Show unscripted, actual command being executed. Show full log.